# Neo4j (Cypher) - Is it possible to use non-implicit aggregation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is fairly straightforward. I've been trying to write a Cypher query which uses an aggregation function - `min()`.

I am trying to obtain the closest node to a particular node using the new Spatial functions offered in Neo4j 3.4. My query currently looks like this:

```
MATCH (a { agency: "Bus", stop_id: "1234" }), (b { agency: "Train" }) 
WITH distance(a.location, b.location) AS dist, a.stop_id as orig_stop_id, b.stop_id AS dest_stop_id 
RETURN orig_stop_id,min(dist)
```

The `location` property is a `point` property and this query does actually do what I want it to do, except for one thing: I'd like to also include the `dest_stop_id` field in the result so that I can actually know which other node corresponds to this minimal distance, however Neo4j seems to aggregate implicitly all fields in the `RETURN` clause that are not inside an aggregate function and the result is I just get a list of all pairs (`orig_stop_id`, `dest_stop_id`) and their distance versus getting just the minimum and the corresponding `dest_stop_id`. Is there any way to specify which fields should be grouped in the result set?

In SQL, `GROUP BY` allows you to specify this but I haven't been able to find a similar function in Cypher.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you need any extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (a { agency: "Bus", stop_id: "1234" }), (b { agency: "Train" }) 
RETURN
  a.stop_id AS orig_stop_id,
  REDUCE(
    s = NULL,
    d IN COLLECT({dist: distance(a.location, b.location), sid: b.stop_id}) |
    CASE WHEN s.dist < d.dist THEN s ELSE {dist: d.dist, dest_stop_id: d.sid} END
  ) AS min_data
```

This query uses `REDUCE` to get the minimum distance and also the corresponding `dest_stop_id` at the same time.

The tricky part is that the first time the `CASE` clause is executed, `s` will be `NULL`. Afterwards, `s` will be a map. The `CASE` clause handles the special `NULL` situation by specifically performing the `s.dist < d.dist` test, which will always evaluate to `false` if `s` is `NULL` -- causing the `ELSE` clause to be executed in that case, initializing `s` to be a map.

*NOTE: Ideally, you should use the labels for your nodes in your query, so that the query does not have to scan every node in the DB to find each node. Also, you may want to add the appropriate indexes to further speed up the query.*

Comment: This works, yep! Thanks. A little bit of an awkward solution though, as essentially this tells me the aggregating functions in Neo4j are incredibly limited as something like this is a common use case.

On the topic of your note, yeah, currently all nodes have the same label and the query was still in "experimental" stages so I didn't worry too much (the actual query is a bit larger than what I presented) and we do have indexes! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could skip the aggregation function and just order the distance and take the top:

```
MATCH (a { agency: "Bus", stop_id: "1234" }), (b { agency: "Train" }) 
WITH distance(a.location, b.location) AS dist, a, b
ORDER BY dist DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN a.stop_id as orig_stop_id, b.stop_id AS dest_stop_id, dist
```

As others here have mentioned you really should use labels here (otherwise is this doing all node scans to find your starting points, this is probably the main performance bottleneck of your query), and have indexes in place so you're using index lookups for both a and b.

EDIT

If you need the nearest when you have multiple starting nodes, you can take the head of the collected elements like so:

```
MATCH (a { agency: "Bus", stop_id: "1234" }), (b { agency: "Train" }) 
WITH distance(a.location, b.location) AS dist, a, b
ORDER BY dist DESC
WITH a, head(collect(b {.stop_id, dist})) as b
RETURN a.stop_id as orig_stop_id, b.stop_id AS dest_stop_id, b.dist as dist
```

We do need to include `dist` into the map projection from `b`, otherwise it would be used as a grouping key along with `a`.

Alternately you could just collect `b` instead of the map projection and then recalculate with the `distance()` function per remaining row.

Comment: That is not a solution as I wish to expand this query to give me back multiple nearest nodes to different starting nodes. As I mentioned above, this query was still in "experimental" stages so I didn't worry too much about labels but I'm aware of their importance, howeverthe  focus of this post was on the issues and limitations of aggregation functionality in Neo4j, not performance. Thank you for your input, however.

Comment: I added an alternate query that doesn't use LIMIT that should do the trick.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the alternate solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use COLLECT for aggregation (note this query isn't checked) :

```
MATCH (a { agency: "Bus", stop_id: "1234" }), (b { agency: "Train" }) 
WITH COLLECT (distance(a.location, b.location)) as distances, a.stop_id as stopId
UNWIND distances as distance
WITH min(distance) as min, stopId 
MATCH (bus { agency: "Bus", stop_id: stopId}), (train{ agency: "Train" }) 
WHERE distance(bus.location, train.location) = distance 
RETURN bus,train, distance
```

Hope this will help you.